# How does the "E" version of Pentax's D-LI90 battery differ from the original?

Tags: pentax, battery

In addition to the original [D-LI90 battery](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/634906-REG/Pentax_39830_D_LI90_Rechargeable_Lithium_Ion_Battery.html) for Pentax K-5 (and other recent cameras), B&H is now offering the [D-LI90(E)](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/946632-REG/pentax_39993_d_li90e_recharegable_li_ion_battery.html) for pre-order. The specs seem identical:  1860mAh, 7.2V. The only difference is that the new version costs $10 more. Is there something else?

Answer (score 2):

The *E* suffix  usually signifies compliance with *European* standards on Restriction of Hazardous Substances ([RoHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_of_Hazardous_Substances_Directive)). They simply have fewer elements which Europe does not like.